# Error messages on physical server not visible in Putty sessions

Tags: centos, ssh, logs, kvm, putty

When I log in to a remote CentOS 7 HOST server using Putty and perform actions with GUEST virtual machines using `kvm` (`virsh`, `virt-install`, etc), I am not alerted to certain errors.

Then, when I visit the physical location of the physical HOST box and view the monitor attached to the host box, I sometimes find the screen filled with repeating error messages that were not visible to the remote Putty sessions.

For example, when I visited the physical box today, I saw that the following error message had repeated on every line of the physical screen:

```
kvm [nnnn] vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr
```

The numbers for `nnnn` changed in some of the lines, and it looked as if countless pages of these errors had been lost as the screen continued to overflow.

**What specific commands would need to be typed in order for these error messages to be accessible via Putty?**  Does any specific output need to be turned on?  Or diverted into a text file?  And how can these messages trigger alert in the Putty session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you are searching for, these messages should be in the `dmesg` log.

Comment: OK. Typing dmesg showed the information. But it seems that I would have to have a second putty session with dmesg running in order to notice these messages while running commands in the first putty window. Can you suggest a better way to be alerted of the information in these messages?

Comment: It is a good programming/scripting practice to check for errors after running function/command. So you can either check new messages in `dmesg` manually, follow the logs in the file itself `/var/log/dmesg` or write some script that will alert you about new messages (for example in PS1 prompt).